# Permission denied: Could not open password file.

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am using Apache Red hat .

I have .htaccess in my /var/www/html with permissions as followed

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache 127 Dec 18 14:17 .htaccess
```

.htaccess has following data set inside it

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd
Require user manu
```

Permissions on var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache apache 40 Dec 16 19:11 .htpasswd
```

When I open my web page on browser, and after putting username and password, the login prompts reappears. Even if the username and password is correct.

Error logs:

(13) Permission denied: Could not open password file: /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd

access to / failed, reason: verification of user id 'manu' not configured

Any help!

Comment: And, probably an obvious question, but what are the permissions on `/var/www/html/server-auth/`?

Comment: Permissions on server-auth
**drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Dec 17 16:12 server-auth/**

Comment: If you have SELinux enabled, you can test by disabling it temporarily `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`.

Comment: @bangal, yes it works by disabling it temporarily. So to use .htaccess, I have to disable SELinux ?

Comment: @user1486269 Or you could figure out what you'd need to do within Selinux to make it work. You could use [audit2allow](http://linux.die.net/man/1/audit2allow), for example. Learning about selinux is pretty useful down the road; the point of selinux is to increase security, so disabling it will have a lot of nasty side-effects from a security perspective.

Comment: Please follow the advise from @ParthianShot  If I could upvote that more than once, I would.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are having this problem because of SELinux security context.

To overcome this you need to change the selinux label of the directory/file in question.

You can find out the apache process security context using `ps axZ | grep httpd`.

And check the same for `ls -Z /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd`

To adjust the directory labeling try: `chcon` command (it's like `chown`).
To make it permanent you may use: `semanage` command.

Detail instructions and a must read here: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Answer (score 4):

With SELinux enabled Apache is unable to read files unless they are of the same type domain as the running process.

First, check the type domain of the httpd process.

```
ps axZ|grep httpd
```

Second, check the type domain of the .htpasswd file.

```
ls -Z /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd
```

Use the command `chcon` to change the domain of the file to match that of the httpd process.

Example:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd
```

This will change it permanently but the default SELinux context will be re-applied if the file system were to be "relabeled".  If a user initiates the relabel process SELinux will read rules from /etc/selinux/*/contexts/files and apply the rules to the file system.  To avoid that from changing files modified with `chcon` you have to create a new rule using the command `semanage`.

Example:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd
```

Use `chcon` first, test by looking at the audit log in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  When you are sure the correct SELinux rules are applied, save your changes with `semanage`.

You use the `restorecon` command if you need to rollback your changes.  `restorecon` reads the rules from /etc/selinux/*/contexts/files and applies them to the file system.

Example:

```
restorecon -v /var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd
```

Read more about SELinux on CentOS here https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your AuthUserFile in

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile "/var/www/html/server-auth/.htpasswd"
Require user manu
```

That solved the issues for me.