# Docker httpd & htaccess - Could not open password file

Tags: .htaccess, docker, httpd, htpasswd

I have an error that I can't resolve, even with my last researches.

**Folder structure:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   105 Aug  8 15:58 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21371 Aug  8 16:05 my-httpd.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug  8 15:37 www
```

**1 - I create an image of apache with a simple Dockerfile**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Command:

```
docker build -t apache .
```

**2 - I run a container with the new image**

Command:

```
docker run -v /MY_PATH/www/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ -dit --name apache -p 80:80 apache
```

**3 - I want to protect access of the www folder, with htaccess**

Folder structure:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  116 Aug  8 15:37 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   46 Aug  8 15:34 .htpasswd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  169 Aug  7 10:52 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  354 Aug  7 10:56 master.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26 Aug  7 10:57 robots.txt
```

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /MY_PATH/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**4 - I try to access the index.html on my browser**

The connexion windows appears, I type my login, and password.

Then I have a *500 Internal Server Error*

**5 - Logs said that "Could not open password file"**

When I check the apache container logs, I have this:

```
[Fri Aug 09 07:19:58.458778 2019] [authn_file:error] [pid 7:tid 140331369154304] (2)No such file or directory: [client 194.214.141.5:64325] AH01620: Could not open password file: /MY_PATH/www/.htpasswd
194.214.141.5 - user [09/Aug/2019:07:19:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 528
[Fri Aug 09 07:19:58.534805 2019] [authn_file:error] [pid 7:tid 140331135788800] (2)No such file or directory: [client 194.214.141.5:55037] AH01620: Could not open password file: /MY_PATH/www/.htpasswd, referer: http://mywebsite.com/
```

**6 - I need your help :)**

I search many times on Google, the only thing I found is about "SELinux", like this: [Permission denied: Could not open password file.](https://serverfault.com/questions/744078/permission-denied-could-not-open-password-file)

I'm not sure that is the same here with the use of Docker.

So if someone can help me, it would be great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache in the container does not know about your external path `/MY_PATH/www/`, you need to use the path inside the container:

```
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/.htpasswd
```

Comment: Oh damn that was it. I'm ashamed :')

Thank you!